# Should I change Damper body of SR Suntour XCM Fork

Tags: repair, fork

I've disassembled the fork and checked the "Damper body" whether it was working correctly.

It sounded a little bit strange. but I am not sure whether it was OK. *The reason for disassembling was due to the fork wasn't working when it was unlocked*.

Here is a video

The question is should I change this? Is that OK?

Where can I find the same replacement part? Looks like it's sold out.

https://www.srsuntour.us/products/specialized-bicycle-mcd-cartridge?_pos=1&_sid=7f51ba5ec&_ss=r&variant=12180476199006

Local bike stores refer me to buy a new expensive fork, currently it's not an option for me.

Comment: What was it doing when unlocked?

Comment: When I ride, the fork doesn't shrink when pushing it down. However I don't have spare part for that damper body and I will start assembling it again (after cleaning of course)